# bootstrap 4 tabs animation

Tags: jquery, animation, tabs, twitter-bootstrap-4

I am trying to animate a tab pane on a bootstrap 4 nav.

Here is my sample code:

```css
.tab-pane {
  transform: translateY(100%);
  transition: transform 2s;
}
.tab-pane.active {
  transform: translateY(0%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css">

<nav class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
  <a class="nav-item nav-link active" id="nav-home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-home" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-home" aria-selected="true">Home</a>
  <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="nav-profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-profile" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-profile" aria-selected="false">Profile</a>
  <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="nav-contact-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-contact" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-contact" aria-selected="false">Contact</a>
</nav>
<div class="tab-content" id="nav-tabContent">
  <div class="tab-pane active" id="nav-home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-home-tab">
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. 
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="nav-profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-profile-tab">
  type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. 
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="nav-contact" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-contact-tab">
    It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. 
  </div>
</div>
```

In theory, the text in each tab pane should come from the bottom, but each time I change the tab I find it in the final position. There is definitely something I don't understand about this setup, could anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Please note, that you use Beta 1 resources in your example by referencing `4.0.0-beta`. You should use `4.0.0-beta.2` instead.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The problem here is that `.tab-pane`s without the `.active` class have `display: none;` set, but css transition does not work when transitioning from that state.

So you have two options here:

- You could override how Bootstrap handles the inactive tabs, and instead of using the display property, you could use –let’s say– the visibility property to show/hide the tabs. Just make sure display: block is enforced.
- The easier solution though would be simply to use `css animation` with key-frames, as opposed to `css transition`. The former solution works with display; none as well. The example below is an example for this.

```css
.tab-pane.active {
    animation: slide-down 2s ease-out;
}

@keyframes slide-down {
    0% { opacity: 0; transform: translateY(100%); }
    100% { opacity: 1; transform: translateY(0); }
}
```

```html
<nav id="myTab" class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    <a class="nav-item nav-link active" id="nav-home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-home" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-home" aria-selected="true">Home</a>
    <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="nav-profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-profile" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-profile" aria-selected="false">Profile</a>
    <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="nav-contact-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-contact" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-contact" aria-selected="false">Contact</a>
</nav>

<div class="tab-content" id="nav-tabContent">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="nav-home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-home-tab">
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. 
    </div>

    <div class="tab-pane" id="nav-profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-profile-tab">
        type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. 
    </div>

    <div class="tab-pane" id="nav-contact" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-contact-tab">
        It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. 
    </div>
</div>


<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Elegant solution! However I think you can ommit the 100% key since that's its original state.

Answer (score 6):

Here is the better solution using transition instead of animation

```css
.tab-pane.fade {
  transition: all 0.2s;
  transform: translateY(1rem);
}

.tab-pane.fade.show {
  transform: translateY(0rem);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-SI27wrMjH3ZZ89r4o+fGIJtnzkAnFs3E4qz9DIYioCQ5l9Rd/7UAa8DHcaL8jkWt" crossorigin="anonymous">


<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link active" id="home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#home" role="tab" aria-controls="home" aria-selected="true">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" id="profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#profile" role="tab" aria-controls="profile" aria-selected="false">Profile</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" id="contact-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#contact" role="tab" aria-controls="contact" aria-selected="false">Contact</a>
  </li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
  <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">Raw denim you probably haven't heard of them jean shorts Austin. Nesciunt tofu stumptown aliqua, retro synth master cleanse. Mustache cliche tempor, williamsburg carles vegan helvetica. Reprehenderit butcher retro keffiyeh dreamcatcher synth. Cosby sweater eu banh mi, qui irure terry richardson ex squid. Aliquip placeat salvia cillum iphone. Seitan aliquip quis cardigan american apparel, butcher voluptate nisi qui.
</div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="profile-tab">Food truck fixie locavore, accusamus mcsweeney's marfa nulla single-origin coffee squid. Exercitation +1 labore velit, blog sartorial PBR leggings next level wes anderson artisan four loko farm-to-table craft beer twee. Qui photo booth letterpress, commodo enim craft beer mlkshk aliquip jean shorts ullamco ad vinyl cillum PBR. Homo nostrud organic, assumenda labore aesthetic magna delectus mollit. Keytar helvetica VHS salvia yr, vero magna velit sapiente labore stumptown. Vegan fanny pack odio cillum wes anderson 8-bit, sustainable jean shorts beard ut DIY ethical culpa terry richardson biodiesel. Art party scenester stumptown, tumblr butcher vero sint qui sapiente accusamus tattooed echo park.</div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="contact" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="contact-tab">Etsy mixtape wayfarers, ethical wes anderson tofu before they sold out mcsweeney's organic lomo retro fanny pack lo-fi farm-to-table readymade. Messenger bag gentrify pitchfork tattooed craft beer, iphone skateboard locavore carles etsy salvia banksy hoodie helvetica. DIY synth PBR banksy irony. Leggings gentrify squid 8-bit cred pitchfork. Williamsburg banh mi whatever gluten-free, carles pitchfork biodiesel fixie etsy retro mlkshk vice blog. Scenester cred you probably haven't heard of them, vinyl craft beer blog stumptown. Pitchfork sustainable tofu synth chambray yr.
</div>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-3qaqj0lc6sV/qpzrc1N5DC6i1VRn/HyX4qdPaiEFbn54VjQBEU341pvjz7Dv3n6P" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.YourClass.active {
    animation: opac 1.5s
}

@keyframes opac {
    from {
        opacity: 0
    }

    to {
        opacity: 1
    }
}
```

Fade in animation